# RESULT_OK cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, processing

IM having a problem with this line, I'm trying to create a app for android using processing, I'm new with android.
This is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data){
    if(requestCode==0){

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    BACKGND=2; //Set the background to GREEN
    } else {
    BACKGND=1; //Set the background to RED
    }
    }
    }
```

And im getting the following error:

```
1. ERROR in /tmp/android6837327122296929778sketch/src/processing/test/sketch_151209a/sketch_151209a.java (at line 52)
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                 ^^^^^^^^^
RESULT_OK cannot be resolved to a variable
```

///////UPDATE////////

Here is the complete code:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
int BACKGND=0; //Set the background to BLUE

//Get the default Bluetooth adapter
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


/*The startActivityForResult() launches an Activity which is
used to request the user to turn Bluetooth on. 
 The following onActivityResult() method is called when the 
 Activity exits. */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   data){
 if(requestCode==0){

 if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
 BACKGND=2; //Set the background to GREEN
 } else {
 BACKGND=1; //Set the background to RED
 }
 }
}

void setup(){
 orientation(LANDSCAPE);

 /*IF Bluetooth is NOT enabled, 
 then ask user permission to enable it */
 if (!bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
 Intent requestBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
 startActivityForResult(requestBluetooth, 0);
 }
}

void draw(){
 if(BACKGND==0){
 background(10,10,255); //Set background to BLUE
 } else if(BACKGND==1) {
 background(255,10,10); //Set background to RED
 } else {
 background(10,255,10); //Set background to GREEN
 }
}
```

Comment: where is onActivityResult declared ? Fragment or Activity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RESULT_OK` is a constant of the Activity class. If this code is executing in a Fragment the variable wouldn't be resolved.

Reference like this:

`Activity.RESULT_OK`

Comment: I've tried that but i get the following error

    1. ERROR in /tmp/android1989785468487631807sketch/src/processing/test/sketch_151209a/sketch_151209a.java (at line 52)
 if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                  ^^^^^^^^
    Activity cannot be resolved to a variable
----------

Comment: Just covering the bases. Was Activity imported? It needs to be android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK

Comment: From the code you've added, this code doesn't appear to be in a class and I also don't see the import for the Activity class. This code needs to be in an Activity or Fragment of some kind. You should have `SomeActivity extends Activity` or `SomeFragment extends Fragment` or similar for your class declaration. You also need `import android.app.Activity;`

Comment: Thanks! adding the "import android.app.Activity; "  made it, that was what I needed.